# What does "sanction" actually mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, contradiction

I have read this word quite often and always tried to elicit its meaning from the context and circumstances in which it was said.. More often than not I took it as a word for *official ban* or *penalty*.. until recently when I was watching an interview in which the interviewee felt offended over a question asked by someone in the audience and refused to answer it and said "she do not sanction impoliteness"...contextually meaning *approval* or *consent*. 
When I googled its meaning, it offered me two usages :-

1. a threatened penalty for disobeying a law or rule; *syn*- *penalty, ban, deterrent*, *correction*
2. official permission or approval for an action; *syn*- *permission ,authority, agreement*

Both of them are almost contradictory and do not offer an unambiguous understanding when used in  sentence.

For example: *the court sanctioned the proposal*. 
Did the court approved or deterred?

Comment: It has two, conflicting meanings. There are other words in English like this. Sometimes a sentence is ambiguous.

Comment: In your example "The court sanctioned the proposal.", it seems strange to me that a proposal could be penalized or deterred from further action for doing something wrong -- therefore, in this case, sanctioned seems to mean approved.  Sentences with words like sanction and moot can be tricky to decipher.

Comment: "legitimize" or "harm legitimately"